# How to store Qt gui layout and restore it

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt gui application that uses dock widgets and similar items, which user can adjust themselves.

I want the layout to stay on application restart. The application already has some functions to save and load user configuration, but I have no idea how would I store a layout (positions of docks, their size etc), neither how would I restore them.

Is there any easy way of doing this? Or do I have to check the size, position and location of every single element and store it separately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For storing your dock windows layout you can use `QMainWindow::saveState(int version)` and `QMainWindow::restoreState(const QByteArray &state, int version)` in combination with `QSettings` class.

Example from [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qmainwindow.html#saveState):

```
void MyMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    QSettings settings("MyCompany", "MyApp");
    settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
    settings.setValue("windowState", saveState());
    QMainWindow::closeEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: does it have to be inside of QSettings? My application uses xml to store the configuration.

Comment: @Petr: using `QSettings` is not a requirement. You can store the byte array in the format and file that is most convenient for you. The main point is using `saveState()` and `restoreState()` functions that use `QByteArray`.

Comment: it just don't work :( should I first create gui and then call it or call it and then create gui? (I didn't make the layout of dock widgets in visual editor, but it's in source code)

Comment: @Petr: you need to create your GUI first (tool bars, dock windows, etc.). Than get the state with `saveState()` function and store it. On next session (when you start your GUI) you need to create your GUI and call `restoreState()` with the saved byte array. It doesn't meter how you create your dock windows: in visual editor or with API.

Comment: that's precisely how I do that, saveState produces empty array, saveGeometry produces some binary data, but after I load them nothing happens

Comment: @Petr: Do you have your parent-child relationships set correctly?

Comment: Ok it seems to work now, it just doesn't seem to store the width of some components, otherwise it's ok

Comment: More at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288635/any-easy-way-to-store-dock-widows-layout-and-sizes-in-settings-with-qt